# How to split the string using comma delimiter in Jenkins Groovy script?

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-groovy

I have tried to get all the solution files(*.sln) in a given path and print it individually by split the string(each solution file path) using comma delimiter. Programming script language am using is Jenkins Groovy. Am getting the below specified error when build the Jenkins job. Any one please look into this and guide me to proceed in a right way.

```
def finder = new FileNameFinder()
def files = finder.getFileNames 'D:\jobs', '**/*.sln'
def resultList = files.tokenize(",")

for(i=0; i<resultList.size();i++)
{
println resultList[i]
}
```

Error Details:

```
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList.tokenize() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [,]
Possible solutions: toUnique(), toUnique(), toUnique(java.util.Comparator), takeWhile(groovy.lang.Closure), toUnique(groovy.lang.Closure), toUnique(java.util.Comparator)
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

Myself itself found an answer for my above problem. Please find below the modified working code.

```
def finder = new FileNameFinder()
def files = finder.getFileNames 'D:\jobs', '**/*.sln'
assert files instanceof List  
println files.size()+" solution files found in the given path. Below are the found solution files details. \n"
for(i=0;i<files.size();i++)
{
println files[i];
}
```

Thanks